# AND doesn't work in an IF statement embedded in an array formula

Tags: excel

I have an array formula in a cell. This formula displays the line number of a cell at the condition that the cell contains "FAIL" (and displays the line numbers with a coma separator). I wanted to add another condition to this formula so I tried to use AND but it now doesn't work anymore and I don't know why.

The original IF that worked looks like that:

`IF(Y23:Z6000="FAIL";ROW(Y23:Z6000);"")`

And what I want to write is

`IF(AND(Y23:Z6000="FAIL";NOT(ISBLANK(A23:A6000));ROW(Y23:Z6000);"")`

I have also tried with `A23:A6000<>""` but same outcome.

---

The whole formula is this one:
`{=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;IF(AND(Y23:Z6000="FAIL";NOT(ISBLANK(A23:A6000)));ROW(Y23:Z6000);""))}`

---

Can you please help me figure out what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array formulas do not like `AND` or `OR` Either nest IFs or use `*` or `+` respectively:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;IF((Y23:Z6000="FAIL")*(NOT(ISBLANK(A23:A6000)));ROW(Y23:Z6000);""))
```

Array formulas require confirmation with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.