# Is the AND function not the proper function for referencing values that are TRUE in both columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, boolean

[image]

I am attempting to show the date in a cell that is between the 2 dates. Today is 2021/06/14. So in theory the cell above the first column of dates should show 2020/11/01. For some reason, it keeps showing false but when I check the formula, there are definitely 2 True values and that is "2020/11/01" and "2021/10/31". If someone can help me with this, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: AND will take array arguments and return a single value, so it is looking at the whole and because there is at least one that is FALSE it returns FALSE for the whole.

Comment: @ScottCraner Do you know a function that can replace AND and do the job? I'm doing a horrible job at phrasing this question on google.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429763/and-doesnt-work-in-an-if-statement-embedded-in-an-array-formula

Comment: @ScottCraner That was insightful. I removed AND and used nested "IF" and "*" within the formula. However, I can't get it to return True. Do you have a function that I can look into?

Comment: @bigbass001 - Please use ISO date format where possible as it avoids all confusion. `MM/dd/yyyy` is particularly confusing as 95% of the world does not use it.

Comment: @ScottCraner: did you get 'n/a' or #SPILL! "? Not sure where the nested comes into play either; it should translate into something virtually identical to what I've proposed below, minus the index (which would return a spill in the cell you've used, i.e. J4, as there are 2 dates that satisfy the criteria.  Give below a go and let me know if it doesn't work - think you've already approved - glad to see it worked out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the correct syntax for dates (and by 'correct' I mean consistent, i.e. either dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy, but not both simultaneously), you would see that your version of the equation evaluates to the following:

```
IF(AND({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE},{TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE}),J5:J9,"n/a")
```

The AND statement will only evaluate to True if both sub arrays are identical (i.e. if all dates were = today).

One way to get the desired result is as follows (screenshot refers, noting the consistent use of date format in both columns...):

[image: Reference first date in col. J to satisfy col J <= today() <= col K]

i.e. using the following eqn:

```
=INDEX(J5:J9,MATCH(1,(J5:J9<=TODAY())*(TODAY()<=K5:K9),0))
```

If you have Office 365, then you could return all such instances using the following, per 2nd screenshot below:

```
=FILTER($J$5:$J$9,(J5:J9<=TODAY())*(TODAY()<=K5:K9))
```

[image: Reference all instances that satisfy given criteria re: dates]

Comment: This was explained really well. Thanks for your time putting an example together. I now understand the fault of using the AND statement. I think this Index and Match function may be my new best friend. I wish you the best. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers bigbass001 (tbh I dig the alias - really funny/cool haha!  Upvote is best thanks I can receive!